# Tikz How to get a loop at the end of an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need to obtain a "hanging" edge looking as shown below:

[image]
How to do that?

---

do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX-SE. When asking a question, please try to include a MWE (Minimum Working example) that includes what you may have tried already.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! This may be a start. There are many possible variations, most notably with the `hobby` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[circle,draw] (A){\phantom{A}};
 \draw[thick,-{Latex[bend]}] (A) to[out=0,in=170] ++ (pi/2,0) coordinate (pft)
  to[out=-10,in=0] ++ (-0.2,-0.5) to[out=180,in=-100] ([xshift=-3mm]pft);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Schrödinger's cat, it resolved my problem. Thanks a lot!